How to create jsonb index for top level keys in PostgreSQL?
I have json data in my jsonb column json_struct with the following structure:
{
    "key1":{
            ...
            "value": "foo",
            ...
           },
    "key2":{
            ...
            "value": "bar",
            ...
           }
}

I want to create a index on the keys to speed up queries like:
SELECT * from my_data_table where json_struct -> 'key1' ->> 'value' like 'foo' AND json_struct -> 'key2' ->> 'value' like 'bar';

The problem is that I cannot create an index for each key because there are too many (>10.000) of them.
Any idea how to index my table to speed up my query ?

perhaps GIN index on the JSONB column

unfortunately that even somehow slowed my query down a little bit :(

How like that example are your real queries?  In your example, neither of the LIKE patterns have wildcards.

should using = instead of 'like' speed up my query  ? in my case I didnt affect the speed much

There is no single index that can do that; the only option is to create an index for each attribute you want to compare. If you wanted to compare with =, a GIN index would work, but not for pattern matching.
That is not a specific shortcoming of PostgreSQL's JSON implementation: even if your attributes were regular table columns, you would need two indexes if you want to perform an efficient LIKE search on two columns.

this is the exact pattern I'm moving away from another database to postgres for key value support. any pointers how I can speed it up without normalizing ?

I don't know any. PostgreSQL's JSON support is good, but a relational database will always work best with a relational model. But even with a relational model, you would need two indexes if you want to perform LIKE searches on two columns. I'll edit the answer.
